SD drive not showing up on my wife's Macbook Pro but it does show up on my Macbook and my Mac Mini
I've got an SD drive that shows up on my Mac Mini and my MacBook but it won't show up on my wife's Macbook Pro.
I erased it earlier on my Mini, but I tried that again when I got it to show up in Disk Utility because it showed there but wouldn't mount.
I acted like it was erasing but it wouldn't mount. Why?

Which version of macOS is your Mac Mini and your wife's Mac running? What is the file system format of the SD drive (see https://support.apple.com/guide/disk-utility/file-system-formats-dsku19ed921c/22.6/mac/15.0 and https://serverfault.com/a/276099/134501)?

Could be the SD drive is near death and cannot be trusted. Retire it to the recycling bin and get a new drive: they're inexpensive enough to replace. From years of experience, I've learned never to trust SD drives, (and USB Thumb drives for that matter,) to contain crucial files for any length of time. The chances that they will cease to function when you most need them is high. Just my $0.02.

It shows up on 2 different comupters but not this one, and other sd devices do show up on this computer.

Showing up on some computers and not others is a symptom of a defective or failing drive. As much as you don't want to, it seems to be the consensus that you should seriously consider replacing the drive.
